# If a flagpole visualizes a Pauli spinor, what visualizes a Dirac spinor?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors

@AndrewSteane writes in his textbook that a Pauli spinor is a flagpole - with length, direction, flag orientation - and a sign.

A Dirac spinor is a more complicated object. What is the most intuitive visualization of a Dirac spinor?

**Update:** Steane proposes two flagpoles.

The 8 parameters of a Dirac spinor are 1 magnitude, 3 flagpole angles, 3 boost parameters (such as vx vy vz), and 1 fraction specifying particle and antiparticle components.

Does it make sense to contract the latter 4 numbers into a second flagpole? How can one relate the two descriptions?

Comment: A flagpole and an antimatter flagpole ?

Comment: This would be possible: but how does one relate the two poles to the boost parameters?

Comment: Why not 2 spinning flagpoles with opposite chirality

Comment: @Craig Steane proposes this as well. But then, how are matter and antimatter flagpoles related to the boost parameters?

Comment: For what its worth I think it's not a great analogy. Nothing will give you intuition for the various spinors except for working with them.

Comment: @Craig Does the relative orientation of the two flagpoles, or their relative length, depend on the matter/antimatter content?

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Steane also writes, a Dirac spinor is essentially
a pair of two Pauli spinors (see [An introduction to spinors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3824),
chapter "VI. Dirac spinors and particle physics"):

> Such a pair is called a *bispinor*
> or *Dirac spinor*. It can conveniently be written as a
> $4$-component complex vector, in the form
> $$\Psi=\begin{pmatrix}\phi_R \\ \chi_L\end{pmatrix} \tag{78}$$
> where it is understood that each entry is a $2$-component
> spinor, $\phi_R$ being right-handed and $\chi_L$ left-handed.

Therefore I would visualize a Dirac spinor by a pair of two
flagpoles (each with length, direction, flag orientation, and sign).

Comment: He's talking about Weyl spinors. I don't think a Dirac spinor can be interpreted as two Pauli spinors (as I understand the term).

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Steane says that a spinor is a flagpole and a sign. But how can a flagpole be right-handed or left-handed?

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch How does one relate the two poles to the boost parameters and to the spin orientation  and also to the particle.antparticle ratio?

Comment: @KlausK I don't know. Sorry.